# Best practice for designing GATT server service

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

How would you design a GATT server service that will be used for getting long-string information? What is the best practice for that? I saw some implementations used two characteristics one uses the property write-without-response and the other uses notify. The device sends a command to write-without-response characteristics and gets notified from the other one but it didn't seem like a proper design.

Is there any suggestion for better implementation? Or there is a reason to use it like that?

Comment: You might find the following blog has some relevant points: https://punchthrough.com/serial-over-ble/

Comment: Well, this answer is more than enough for me. Thank you.